# Как выбрать значение в строке Понедельник и в столбце ИЦТМС 1к 1 bo 090302 ИСитвс

Tags: python, парсер, pdf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabulate import tabulate
tables = read_pdf("C:\\Users\\yegor\\Desktop\\parser_pdf\\IZ1.pdf",encoding = 'cp1251',pages='1')
```

Comment: Пример pdf скиньте. Там с русским языкам не все так просто

Comment: Хм, погуглил, PDF нельзя вставить в вопрос. Ссылка file:///C:/Users/yegor/Desktop/parser_pdf/IZ1.pdf подойдёт? Я просто совсем новичок, не знаю как ссылку на PDF вставить :)

Comment: Эта ссылка подойдёт если предоставить её вместе с компьютером))

Comment: Вы с сайта вуза их брали? Ссылка на страницу пойдёт

Comment: https://mgsu.ru/student/Raspisanie_zanyatii_i_ekzamenov/fayly-raspisaniya-dlya-skachivaniya/IZ%20I.pdf